# how do I get the viewport position relative to the screen?

Tags: javascript

#### My question

What JavaScript code will tell me where the **viewport** of the **browser** is located relative to the **screen**?

#### Context

My web application includes an applet that allows taking a snapshot via *java.awt.Robot* (the applet's jar is of course signed and is privileged to perform this).

The problem is that Robot's *createScreenCapture* works with rectangles relative to the entire screen, whereas I want to capture a rectangle relative to the viewport.

A browser can obviously be anywhere on the screen, but even if it is maximized (and therefore begins at the top left of the screen, i.e. {0,0}) I still don't know how much the content is pushed down because of the window header or some toolbars.

#### My research so far

It seems only IE gives the viewport position through *window.screenTop/Left*.

Chrome supports these, but they hold the browser position.

FF doesn't support these, instead it has *screenX/Y*, but like Chrome they hold the browser position.

#### Making sure we all use the same terminology

**Screen** - AKA the desktop. for example I have a WSXGA+ (1680x1050) display. I use Windows and my taskbar is always shown at the bottom so it consumes about 50 pixels vertically.

**Browser** - a window that may or may not have various toolbars: address and/or bookmarks bar at the top, status/add-on bars at the bottom, etc.

**Viewport** - where a URL is actually being rendered.

Comment: Sorry mate, I was in a hurry and I didn't pay attention to the full question...

Comment: All DOM events give you the mouse coordinates relative to the viewport and relative to the screen. Just do `event.screenX - event.clientX` and your are ready to go. You can do it in response to any event like `mousemove`, `mouseover`, `mousedown`, etc..

Comment: @GetFree Please go to example.com using Chrome, open devtools, paste this `document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {console.log(e.screenX - e.clientX)})` and click a few times to see the number. Now hit ⌘-shift-B / ctrl-shift-B to toggle the bookmarks bar. Click again. Is it a different number? No? Then you didn't answer this question from 2012. But thanks for trying!

Comment: @targumon, you must be joking. The bookmarks bar changes the `Y` coordinate not the `X` coordinate.

Comment: @GetFree sorry, you're right! (shouldn't have replied at midnight and be confused by *your* reply that used X instead of Y)
Anyway, the problem with your solution is that is assumes a mouse event such as click. It won't work for a scroll event for example. It certainly won't work for a keyboard event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your applet knows its location via getLocationOnScreen()

Here is a Java applet that prints the screen location of the mouse cursor while you are inside of it:

ScreenTest.java:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
public class ScreenTest extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener
{
    public ScreenTest()
    {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        Point loc=getLocationOnScreen();

        String s=(loc.getX()+e.getX())+":"+(loc.getY()+e.getY());
        g.clearRect(0,0,1000,100);
        g.drawString(s, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

screentest.html:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <applet code="ScreenTest.class" name="screenTest" height=100 width=1000></applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a simpler example called by javascript. The applet is 1px by 1px in the upper left corner of the page.

ScreenTest2.java:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.applet.Applet;
public class ScreenTest2 extends Applet
{
    public String test(int x, int y)
    {
        Point loc=getLocationOnScreen();
        return (loc.getX()+x)+":"+(loc.getY()+y);
    }
}
```

screentest2.html:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body onclick="buttonClick(event);" style="margin:0; border:0; height:800px">
        <applet code="ScreenTest2.class" name="screenTest2" height=1 width=1></applet>
    </body>
    <script>
        function buttonClick(evt)
        {
            alert(screenTest2.test(evt.clientX,evt.clientY));
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @chac The way I understand the question, the coordinates are needed for a call to java.awt.Robot from within the applet, so this should be a workable solution.

Comment: you're right!! please excuse my useless comment...and i can stop searching the old code...

Comment: @JonHulka please correct me if I'm wrong, but getLocationOnScreen() works only when the mouse is over the applet. This applet is 1*1px with the sole purpose of taking a screencap of the REST of the page. The page contains components in iframes with various technologies - Flex/Flash, plain HTML, 'real' Applet, Silverlight, etc. - and Robot is the only tool we've found which hooks on the display, thus reliably perform a true WYSIWYG screencap.

Comment: You can see a video of the product here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TAySeyF4bU skip to 5:00 and see how a user creates a new dashboard page. at 5:55 they hit the 'save' button, and at that moment we take a screenshot, so we have a thumbnail for this page.

Comment: @targumon getLocationOnScreen works when the mouse is not over the applet. It returns the location of the applet's upper left corner. I'll put up another example that doesn't use the mouse events.

Comment: I've added another example. The applet takes coordinates passed by javascript and adds its offset. The coordinates passed to the applet should be relative to the applet's position within the viewport (in this case 0,0).

Answer (score 4):

Jon Hulka's answer totally earned him his credit - works perfect for me!

If someone else gets here and need a solution that doesn't use applets (my question asked for JavaScript code), they can try the (compromising*) solution below.

*= It assumes browsers don't have too much stuff at the bottom of their windows.

```
function cacheElemImage(element) {
    var x, y, pos = findPosition(element);
    // screenTop/Left supported on all except FF. screenX/Y supported on all except IE.
    // In addition IE returns viewport top/left while FF & Chrome return browser window top/left.
    // Opera & Safari yet to be tested.
    if (isIE()) {
        x = window.screenLeft;
        y = window.screenTop;
    } else {
        var borderWidth = (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth) / 2;
        x = window.screenX + borderWidth;
        y = window.screenY + window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight - borderWidth;
    }
    x += pos[0]; // adjust for the element position
    y += pos[1];
    var width  = element.offsetWidth;
    var height = element.offsetHeight;
    cacheImage(x, y, width, height); // call the applet with the Robot
}

function findPosition(oElement) {
    if (typeof(oElement.offsetParent) != 'undefined') {
        for (var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent) {
            posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
            posY += oElement.offsetTop;
        }
        return [posX, posY];
    } else {
        return [oElement.x, oElement.y];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I think there is still some confusion regarding mouse position. As illustrated by the second example, ScreenTest2.java, the mouse position has nothing to do with getLocationOnScreen(), the returned coordinate is actually the upper-left corner of the Applet, which can be positioned using css to anywhere you want it on the page. In other words, getLocationOnScreen() has no relation to the mouse whereabouts.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks!  Could you expound on your caveat about "bottom of window"?

Comment: @JoeCoder , The developer tools I sometimes use (F12 in Chrome, ctrl-shift-K in Firefox, etc.) occupy some real estate at the bottom so the viewport doesn't go all the way down. Actual users are not expected to use these while using the app, so no problem here. However, Internet Explorer may display a 'status bar', which isn't very tall, but might ruin the snapshot a bit.