# Color at Certain Pixel location inside Java Applet?

Tags: java, colors, applet, pixel

I am currently making a paint like program with Java Applets. I want to simulate a bucket tool by using recursion and checking each pixel around a given point, however I am having trouble getting the RGB value at a given pixel.

Is there a way to do something such as

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.getPixelAt(X, Y);
}
```

Or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Graphics` is virtual concept and does not support what you are trying to do

What you need to do is paint to a surface that you can interact with, something like a `BufferedImage`.

The basic idea would be painting all effects to this buffered image and using `Graphihcs#drawImage` to actually render the image to the screen.

From there you can us `BufferedImage#getRaster` which will provide you with a `WritableRaster` object which has `get/setPixel` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Applet.getLocationOnScreen() and java.awt.Robot.createScreenCapture() to find and capture the part of the applet you want.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254070/how-do-i-get-the-viewport-position-relative-to-the-screen/13281095#13281095) poses a similar problem.