How to get the x,y position of the website viewport inside the browser?
So I can get the width and height of the viewport inside the browser easily with
window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight, but I also want to know the x and y position inside the browser.
Some browsers also have additional panels on the left and bottom and when I open the devTools I also have a panel on the right side, so simply doing window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth is not going to do the trick. What is the cross-browser solution to getting the x and y position in this case?


FYI developer tools can also go on the left.  Cross-browser solution makes no sense when it's browser-specific windows/panels that are opened.

Why would you need to know this? For privacy reasons, I expect and hope it’s impossible. (Then again, I would hope the same for screenX/screenY, but they still exist.)

The "viewport" is the part of the browser that shows the website.  It's top left will always be 0,0 regardless of how many panels or if the page is maximised / located on a different screen etc.

I think the dev tools of all browser can go anywhere, left, right, bottom so it's an issue for all browsers. Since it's possible to get the width and height of the viewport it shouldn't be too far fetched that I should also be able to ge the x and y position relative to the browser UI.
One use case would be, I want to show an arrow in my website to point to a part of the browser UI "click here".

"all browser" - pretty sure Lynx doesn't do that...

This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254070/how-do-i-get-the-viewport-position-relative-to-the-screen

That's correct @fdomn-m. I would need a solution that works also if there is a panel on the bottom, and left or left and right, so getting the x and y is inevitable.

I want to show an arrow in my website to point to a part of the browser UI - you won't be able to render anything from HTML/CSS/Javascript outside the viewport (outside your webpage) - so if you want to eg point at the back button or the address bar, you won't be able to from HTML.   Maybe a browser extension/plugin?

I don't want to show something above the browser UI, but I can point to the UI element inside the website.

Then it doesn't matter if there's a panel open - what's stopping you?   What's not working?  What are you actually trying to do?  See What is an XY Problem (SO)

Check my screenshot. I can resize the downloads panel and I can resize the devtools panel. My website will not be able to tell where the icon next to the url bar is located in relative terms, for example.

Not shown in your screenshot, but I think I understand, eg you might have a big arrow on your site that "normally" sits under the "refresh button" - but with a panel open, it will be offset and sit half-way across the address bar.

"One use case would be, I want to show an arrow in my website to point to a part of the browser UI 'click here'." - that would also require that you know the position of that browser UI element, in relation to the whole browser window - which in modern, customizable browsers, you simply don't.

you can get the x or y position by the [window.screenX][1] or [wndow.screenY][1] this is the mdn doc you can read more about that there.

Thanks for your reply, but screenX and screenY won't help. They are giving the distance between the screen edge and browser window edge. I need the distance between the browser window edge and the actual website viewport.
screenX and screenY don't change if I open or resize my browser panels, such as the dev tools.
